# Disabling certain entries in ListView

Tags: android

I'm trying to disable certain items in my ListView by the following code

```
public class VSsimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements
        Filterable {
    public VSsimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        String s = "mystring"
        if (/*compare an entry in cursor with s*/){
            return false;
        } else 
        return true;

    }
}
```

The problem is `isEnabled` only has one argument position. How do I use the `Curser` used to set the `Adapter` in `isEnabled`?

Comment: Do you have to disable certain rows ?

Comment: @SALMAN Yes, certain rows of the `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't tested it but I guess you just have to move the cursor to the specific row and get the value that should be compared to s. so something like

```
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    String s = "mystring";

    // the database column of the value that you want to compare to s
    int column = 0;
    Cursor cursor = getCursor();
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    String value = cursor.getString(column);

    if (s.equals(value)) {
        return false;
    } else
        return true;

}
```